# Trouble adding users to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

i have a new sharepoint instance in standalone mode. yesterday i was able view newly added users (added in user & groups of computer management) to sharepoint. the search feature in sharepoint brings up the users while adding them to sharepoint.

but today, strangely, new users added to windows are not showing up in the sharepoint user search. hence i am not able to add any new user to my moss instance? I compare the previous users and newly users properties and found nothing different!?

any clue why this is happening?and how to fix this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Has the user profile service stopped working? Check the Shared Service Provider.

Comment: yes its running... i am able to access its details from the central admin console